# How to propagate standard error of medians

Tags: median, error-propagation

I am interested in median-to-median propagation of standard error: The values in my variable (say, $Y$) are all medians (of something, say, $X$), and are each associated with a standard error. Next, I want to summarise this current variable further using median. I am unable to figure out how to propagate the existing median SEs in this last step.

$$ Y_{i} = median(X_{j}) $$
$$ Z = median(Y_{i}) $$

Many threads on Stack Exchange I saw discuss mean-to-mean propagation, which isn't what I want. For mean, the partial derivative required for the propagation formula is only concerned with the summing of individual values, and hence the formula is fairly straightforward (equation 2 [here](https://chemlab.truman.edu/data-analysis/propagation-of-error/)). However, since there is no summing involved in median, I don't know how to proceed with this propagation.

[This post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/292871/uncertainty-propagation-upon-taking-the-median) on Physics SE was the closest I could get, but I am confused as the answer only shows the relationship between uncertainties in mean and median, and doesn't explicitly talk about propagation. According to the linked answer, for large samples:

$$ SE_{median} = SE_{mean} \sqrt{\pi/2} $$

Am I right in interpreting from this that for my purpose, I need to first calculate $ Z^{'} = mean(Y_{i}) $ then find $ SE_{Z^{'}} $ (using the propagation formula for mean), which I will substitute in the formula to get:

$$ SE_{Z} = SE_{Z^{'}}  \sqrt{\pi/2} $$

$$ SE_{Z} = \frac{1}{N} \sqrt{\sum (SE_{Y_{i}})^2}  \sqrt{\pi/2} $$

Surely, there's a more straightforward way to achieve this propagation, directly from the error values of the medians?

Comment: Check the sampling distribution of the Wikipedia article referred to https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median#The_sample_median

Comment: @seanv507 I had seen this article, but haven't made much progress on a second read. I may be missing something but I don't think it throws much light on propagating, again. To clarify though, I am not looking for the theoretical background to this, but rather for a way to do the calculations with my current variables.

Comment: So I don't really understand what you want to do, but statisticians tend to use the mean/variance precisely because errors propagate nicely etc (as opposed to eg median/range).  There is no equivalent for median.  There will be just different approximate formulas.

Comment: @seanv507 Yes, that makes sense. Is the last equation in my question statistically correct? If so, I could propagate the error in a roundabout way by first propagating SE of mean.

Comment: I don't have the time to look at this right now, but typically people use the bootstrap to do things like this. this is likely to work better than these normal approximations. http://www.stat.ucla.edu/~rgould/252w02/bsintro

Comment: In some cases the best you can do is to situation your estimated median-of-medians between the most extreme possibilities, even when you have all the sample counts.  It would therefore help for you to state your actual problem more specifically, so we can understand better what you're dealing with.

Comment: @seanv507 There's probably something I haven't explained properly, because estimating the population median from the sample median (via bootstrapping) is not what I am confused about. In fact, I have already done that---I have calculated $SE_{Y_{i}}$ using bootstrap (resampling with replacement). My actual doubt is regarding how to **propagate** ***this*** error. My data has grouping variables and so what I want to do is summarise the already obtained medians (and their errors) across one particular grouping variable.

Comment: @whuber Do let me know if it's still not clear. In the case of mean, it relatively straightforward because the error can be propagated using partial derivatives of the function (which is ultimately a summation, as the denominator is a constant). So equation 2 in the first link I shared can be adapted for the purpose. However, with median it becomes tricky because the function is applied on the distribution of the data and not the data itself.

Comment: Currently, your question is unintelligible: please explain what the connection might be between "this current variable" and the set of (sample?) medians you already have.  Your question would have no point if you just want to compute the medians of the medians: the usual formula applies.  Evidently, you view each of your medians as estimating something and you want somehow to combine these estimates to estimate something else.  We need to know what the estimands are and more precisely how the estimates were obtained.

Comment: @whuber The values in $Y$ are medians of values in $X$ (which are counts), i.e., sample medians. These values are grouped, i.e., each value in $Y$ corresponds to a group within the grouping variable $A$. I have calculated SE for each value in $Y$ by bootstrapping to get population medians and then calculating their SD. Now, I wish to *ungroup* $Y$, i.e., remove the grouping by $A$. So, I summarise the sample medians by calculating their median (median-of-medians). $Z = median(Y_{i})$. But in this summarisation I also want to take into account the uncertainty associated with each $Y_{i}$.

Comment: What exactly would "remove the grouping" *mean?*  For instance, suppose $A$ is the gender of human subjects and you have samples of heights of male and female adults from a defined population.  Each sample has a median; this can be used to estimate the median height by sex in the population.  What would the median of these medians estimate?  It doesn't correspond to *any* definite population property, because how it is related to the population depends on the sizes of the two samples. Note, too, that the overall population median could be *far* outside the SEs of either group median.

Comment: Wouldn't the median of these medians estimate the median height of the population, both sexes? (With this example of sex as the grouping variable, it might not make much sense to do this, but regardless.) And the SE calculated for this value, propagated from the two individual SEs (which take into account the two sample sizes) could then be used to estimate the population median?

Answer (score 0):

One of the main uses of the bootstrap is to calculate statistics of quantities with no analytical formula.

So if you want the standard error of the median of medians
Then

1. generate a realisation of your raw data
2. calculate your Yis
3. calculate a realisation of Z

Repeat this 1000 times and you have 1000 realizations of Z
Now calculate the standard deviation of these Zs ( or the percentiles etc)

Comment: Does this mean that in the case of median, there is no way to *propagate* the SE calculated for $Y$ (via bootstrapping) to $Z$, and that the SE needs to be calculated via bootstrapping separately for $Z$?

Comment: What I am suggesting is that the standard way of getting the Variance etc of Z is to do a  bootstrap of your Xs and make all the calculations to create the Z.  You do not do 2 bootstraps.  No there is no exact way of propagating the variances.  There are various approximations which might depend on how close your distribution is to normal etc, but the best way of checking the accuracy of the approximations is in any case to use a bootstrap.